# Observing Live data changed by retrofit is not triggering on changed

Tags: java, android, mvvm, retrofit

before all, I checked both questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52859416/android-mvvm-livedata-not-observing) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56091402/login-example-using-retrofit-mvvm-livedata-in-android), neither of them solved my issue.

secondly, I'll be explaining everything in detail, so please excuse me for the long post.

so I'm trying to implement the MVVM in android for the first time, and followed some guides and steps from [tuto1](https://proandroiddev.com/concise-error-handling-with-livedata-and-retrofit-15937ceb555b) and [tuto2](https://proandroiddev.com/mvvm-architecture-viewmodel-and-livedata-part-1-604f50cda1), as cleared in my question, the on changed method in the observer is not triggering, and I can't understand why.
here is my code architecture:

**Authentication.java:**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("service/api/login/")
Call<LoginResponse> login(@Field("username") String username,
                          @Field("password") String password);
```

to handle errors, I implemented a generic request handler following the tuto1:

**GenericRequestHandler.java:**

```
public abstract class GenericRequestHandler<T extends Response> {

private static final String TAG = GenericRequestHandler.class.getName();

abstract protected Call<T> makeRequest();

public final MutableLiveData<DataWrapper<T>> doRequest() {
    final MutableLiveData<DataWrapper<T>> liveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    final DataWrapper<T> dataWrapper = new DataWrapper<>();
    makeRequest().enqueue(new ApiCallback<T>() {
        @Override
        protected void handleResponseData(T data) {
            Log.e(TAG, "handleResponseData: being handled");
            dataWrapper.setData(data);
            liveData.postValue(dataWrapper);
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleError(String message) {
            Log.e(TAG, "handleError: error handled");
            dataWrapper.setErrorMessage(message);
            liveData.postValue(dataWrapper);
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleException(Exception t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "handleException: exception handled");
            dataWrapper.setApiException(t);
            liveData.postValue(dataWrapper);
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleHttpCodes(int code) {
            Log.e(TAG, "handleHttpCodes: code handled");
            dataWrapper.setCode(code);
            liveData.postValue(dataWrapper);
        }
    });
    return liveData;
}
```

}

and then I made a specification from it, to handle signIn:

**SignInRequestHandler.java:**

```
public class SignInRequestHandler extends GenericRequestHandler {

private Authentication service = RestClient.getInstance().create(Authentication.class);
private String username, password;

public SignInRequestHandler(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

@Override
protected Call<LoginResponse> makeRequest() {
    return service.login(username, password);
}

public MutableLiveData<DataWrapper<LoginResponse>> onAuthRequest() {
    return doRequest();
}
}
```

for validation purposes, i'm calling the signin request handler in my Model like so:

```
public MutableLiveData<DataWrapper<LoginResponse>> login() {
    SignInRequestHandler handler = new SignInRequestHandler(this.userName, this.pass);
    return handler.onAuthRequest();
}
```

here is the viewModel:

**LoginVModel.java:**

```
public class LoginVModel extends ViewModel {

private static final String TAG = LoginVModel.class.getName();

private Driver driver; //this is my model
public MutableLiveData<String> username;
public MutableLiveData<String> password;
public MutableLiveData<DataWrapper<LoginResponse>> loginLiveData;

public LoginVModel() {
    driver = new Driver();
    username = new MutableLiveData<>();
    loginLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    password = new MutableLiveData<>();
}

public void onLogin(View view) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onLogin: " + username.getValue() + " " + password.getValue() );
    driver.setUserName(username.getValue()); 
    driver.setPass(password.getValue());
    loginLiveData = driver.login();
}
}
```

for better error handling, i implemented the api observer from tuto1:

**ApiObserver.java:**

```
public class ApiObserver<T> implements Observer<DataWrapper<T>> {
private ChangeListener<T> changeListener;

public ApiObserver(ChangeListener<T> changeListener) {
    this.changeListener = changeListener;
}

@Override
public void onChanged(@Nullable DataWrapper<T> tDataWrapper) {
    if (tDataWrapper != null)
        if (tDataWrapper.getApiException() != null)
            changeListener.onFail(tDataWrapper.getApiException());
        else if (tDataWrapper.getCode() != 0)
            changeListener.handleCodes(tDataWrapper.getCode());
        else if (!tDataWrapper.getErrorMessage().equals(""))
            changeListener.onErrorMessage(tDataWrapper.getErrorMessage());
        else
            changeListener.onSuccess(tDataWrapper.getData());
}


public interface ChangeListener<T> {
    void onSuccess(T dataWrapper);

    void onFail(Exception exception);

    void handleCodes(int code);

    void onErrorMessage(String message);
}
}
```

in the activity, i'm using two-way binding for the email and password, and the login button triggers onLogin from the viewModel:

**SignInActivity.java:**

```
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = SignInActivity.class.getName();
private ActivitySignInBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_sign_in);
    Utilities.setHtmlText(R.string.forget_password, binding.forgetPassword);

    LoginVModel login = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginVModel.class);
    binding.setLoginModel(login);
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

    login.loginLiveData.observe(this, new ApiObserver<>(listener));
}

private ApiObserver.ChangeListener<LoginResponse> listener = new ApiObserver.ChangeListener<LoginResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResponse dataWrapper) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFail(Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        CheckInternetConnection.requestFail();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCodes(int code) {
        // TODO: 10/2/2019 implement code handling here
        Log.e(TAG, "handleCodes: " + code);
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorMessage(String message) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onErrorMessage: i'm here");
        ToastMaker.getInstance().showErrorToast(message);
    }
};

}
```

so i'm trying to log in with wrong data so it triggers an error message, here is the console log:

```
E/driver.itgds.khadametdz.viewmodel.viewmodel.LoginVModel: onLogin: test test
E/driver.itgds.khadametdz.api.requesthandler.GenericRequestHandler: handleError: error handled
```

so the toast isn't showing, neither does the log above it, so please what did I do wrong?

PS: for the live data in generic handler, i tried both .setValue() and .PostValue(), none of them gets the desired result.

**Edit:**
I tried the viewmodel with this method, and it changed nothing.

```
 public void onLogin(View view) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onLogin: " + username.getValue() + " " + password.getValue() );
    driver.setUserName(username.getValue());
    driver.setPass(password.getValue());
//        loginLiveData = driver.login();
    loginLiveData.postValue(driver.login().getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create your ViewModel, you create LiveData like this

```
loginLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

So in activity when you do this

```
login.loginLiveData.observe(this, new ApiObserver<>(listener));
```

you listen this new MutableLiveData<>();. But after you replace reference of LiveData by this

```
loginLiveData = driver.login();
```

So you are not observing the same MutableLiveData. I think the problem is here.

Comment: i thought about this too, and i tried this `loginLiveData.postValue(driver.login().getValue());` with both `.setValue()` and `.postValue()`, and it changed nothing, same problem.

Comment: Yes, or maybe in ViewModel create loginLiveData as MediatorLiveData and addSource from driver.login() when called.

But the best way is to remove LiveData from request handler and use callback, rx or something else, LiveData is useful only in viewmodel to be observed by LifecycleOwner.

Comment: can you explain more about the first point? mediatorLiveData and add source?

Comment: Thanks you for your advice my friend, i tried the second solution, implementing a callback, and then passing it all the way up to the RequestHandler. thank you.

Comment: Ok, you can try to create MutableLiveData in your ViewModel, like your post, and when you call dologin (wich return callback), use loginLiveData.postValue to set new value from callback, it should work like that.